# Deleting property of a argument object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Seems like I can't delete a property from a object param from another promise in nodejs

Say I write

```
Person.save().exec().then(function(err, object){

  create(object) // Lets assume object looks like -> {person : "don"};
})

create: function(object){
  delete object.person;
  console.log(object) // It still has this name property

}
However, If I do a deep copy inside of nodejs code's create call it deleted that property.
```

Then on the contrary, if I write something like

```
function a(){ let abc = { person: "don"}; xyz(abc)}
function xyz(param){
 delete param.person;
 console.log(param); ... It logs an empty object. 
}
a()
```

It does the trick without performing a deep copy. What's the reason for this ?

Comment: There's too little code here for us to see what exactly is going on.  Adding custom properties to promises is generally a bad thing because promises are often chained (new promises created from old ones all the time so it's hard to keep the same object).  In addition, `create(object)` won't call a method like your  show for the `create: function()` definition.  And, `save.then(function(err, object){` is not the signature of a `.then()` handler on a real promise either.  `.then()` handlers are passed only a single argument.

Comment: Yes, It's not. I will write exact code

Comment: Note that `.name` is a reserved property name for some types of objects (like function objects) and has a default configuration that will not allow you to change it.

Comment: When you do `delete object.name;` are you trying to delete the `.name` property?  Or are you trying to delete a property who's name is in the `name` variable?

Comment: Just an example. not using this in real code

Comment: You show a sample object of `{person : "don"};` and then you seem to expect `delete object.name` to do something to that object, but there is no property called "name" on that object.

Comment: If you can successfully remove the property from a copy, but not from the original, then your database must have marked the properties as not configurable or not writable.  So, just work with a copy that you can freely modify.  You can check if this is the case by doing `console.log(delete object.person)`.  If it returns `false` or throws an exception, then the property is configured so it cannot be deleted.

Comment: Oh, and this has nothing to do with the fact that the object is an argument to your function.

Comment: Are you using Mongoose?

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh ok. The database part makes sense now. Actually I did that  with local mongodb before and never had a problem. This time was working with LDAP returned object. Probably the issue is caught. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this is due to the way MongoDB/Mongoose (which looks like it is you're using) objects work.

You can convert a Mongoose object to a regular JS object by calling `.toObject()`. So for example:

```
Person.save().exec().then(function(err, person){

  delete person.name; // won't work

  var newPerson = person.toObject(); // newPerson is now a regular JS object
  delete newPerson.name; // should work
  console.log(newPerson.name); // should return undefined
});
```

Comment: I feel you are right as I had solved this by doing this `var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj))`

Comment: That also works, but is a less efficient version of the `.toObject()` function, which gives you exactly what you need.